# umount filesystem when exit from chroot

Tags: linux, mount, chroot

Is there a way to automatically unmount a filesystem when doing 'exit' command from a chroot?

```
$ mount --bind /proc proc
$ chroot .
~ exit #now in chroot and call exit.
$ # back to main device.
```

I would like proc to be unmounted automatically at exit.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to make an `alias` for `chroot` to run your `umount` command or script after it completes, such as:

```
alias chroot='chroot; umount my/drive'
```

Or maybe use a different name for it, such as `mychroot`.

Another option would be to have script running in the background watching for `chroot` processes and then `umount` the drive when the process is terminated.

Comment: Thank you! The running script in the background is the solution for the case when you have multiple terminals of the same chroot open.